# How to deal with authorization with DRF and React

Tags: django, api, django-rest-framework

I'm building an app using Django as backend and React as frontend, for the user authentication I will use JWT Authentication. My doubt is when I need to get data from the API without the need to be an authenticated user, how I accomplish this? Using API keys?. I read that API keys are not mean for Authentication but authorization? This will be the case?

Comment: If you need to retrieve data from DRF without any authentication, set your **`permission_classes`** to empty as **`permission_classes = []`** in the corresponding view

Answer (score 0):

You can set `authentication_classes = []` in your class for no authentication. If you want permission classes the you can use `permission_classes`

Example:

```py
class SnippetDetail(CreateAPIView):
    authentication_classes = [BasicAuthentication]
    permission_classes = []
```

Reference: https://learnbatta.com/blog/permissions-in-django-rest-framework-82/

Comment: Yeah, but I need authorization, I don't need the API to be public.

Comment: then you can use permission classes